# Mounting ecryptfs using C++ mount function

Tags: c++, c, linux, mount, ecryptfs

I am trying to mount ecryptfs from within a C++ program. I can definitely mount it without it asking questions by issuing this command at the prompt:

```sh
sudo mount -t ecryptfs -o "rw,key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd=geoff,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,no_sig_cache" ~/source/ ~/target/
```

Note that in reality, I am passing a full canonical path in case that matters.

But from within the program I get failure with `errno=EINVAL` after trying by using the `mount()` function with the same arguments:

```cpp
mount("~/source/", "~/target/", "ecryptfs", MS_NODEV, "rw,key=passphrase:passphrase_passwd=geoff,ecryptfs_cipher=aes,ecryptfs_key_bytes=32,ecryptfs_passthrough=n,ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=n,no_sig_cache")
```

The program does launch with `root` privileges and I have checked that I have CAP_SYS_ADMIN.

The `mount()` function returns `-1` and sets `errno` to `EINVAL`.

Have I got the arguments correct? Is this maybe a privileges issue?

**EDIT:** I got it to work by executing mount externally via `system()`, but would still like to use the function because of reasons.

Comment: I'm not sure "~/source" is a correct canonical path, I'd try with a full path, because for me that's as big an invalid value as they get

Comment: Yep already doing that, I just kept it in the example to keep it short.

Comment: `mount` is a POSIX function and has nothing to do with C++

Comment: @phuclv incorrect. Read the actual question.

Comment: @DerfSkren I've read that and what do you mean? **`mount()` is not a C++ function**. Where do you find it in the standard? `C++ mount function` is absolutely incorrect

Comment: @phuclv that's pure semantics and you know it. Many c++ functions are part of libraries such as those in the Linux OS. Claiming that this doesn't exist is pointless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this is because `mount -t ecryptfs` is actually calling the helper executable `mount.ecryptfs`, and it's processing some of the options (in particular, `key=`) itself. What's actually passed to the kernel is different (you can see this by looking at /proc/mounts afterward).

If you look closely at https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/kinetic/en/man7/ecryptfs.7.html, `key=` and `ecryptfs_enable_filename_crypto=` are listed under "MOUNT HELPER OPTIONS" - the actual kernel module's options are `ecryptfs_sig=(fekek_sig)` and `ecryptfs_fnek_sig=(fnek_sig)`.

So, if you want to bypass the helper and do the mount directly, you'd need to load the tokens into the kernel's keyring with https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/keyctl.2.html and replace key= with the resulting token signatures, like mount.ecryptfs did.

It does appear that there is a libecrytpfs with functions in ecryptfs.h like [ecryptfs_add_passphrase_key_to_keyring](https://bazaar.launchpad.net/%7Eecryptfs/ecryptfs/trunk/view/894/src/libecryptfs/key_management.c#L218) which you can (presumably, not tested) use to do this in a way matching the mount.ecryptfs

Comment: Thank you for this detailed response. It was too late to help me (the hack I had went into production) but I hope it helps someone else.